# Route for Controller with Leaf PHP

Tags: php, routes, leaf

I'm using Leaf PHP.
I'm trying to simply create a controller (using php leaf g:controller dsos) which worked.

```
class DsosController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        response()->json([
            'message' => 'DsosController@index output'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create a route to this controller as htts://myserver/Dsos.
So, in /app/routes/_app.php, I added this line:

`app()->get('/dsos', 'DsosController@index');`

But it does not work (error 404).
Any help will be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: can you try firstly this: `app()->get('/dsos', function () {
  echo 'Hello me';
});`. Waat happend?

Comment: Are you running:  `app()->run();`

Comment: I tried, unfortunately, same effect, error 404 not found

Answer (score -1):

I think you should check your file naming or directory structure.
DsosController class should be located in a file named DsosController.php within the appropriate directory based on the namespace

Try this code

**/app/routes/_app.php,**

```php
use App\Controllers\DsosController;

app()->get('/dsos', DsosController::class . '@index');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. DsosController.php is located in App/Controllers directory. I tried your code, same effect unfortunately.